# Android Studio - gradle sync fails with Android Wear

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, wear-os

I'm trying to make an Android wear project in Android Studio, but gradle fails with the following error:

```
Gradle '[project name]' project refresh failed
Error:HTTPS hostname wrong:  should be <services.gradle.org>
```

And in Android Studio logs I see a bunch of exceptions:

```
2015-10-19 13:26:11,488 [ 207654]   INFO - .BaseProjectImportErrorHandler - Failed to import Gradle project at '[my local folder path]' 

org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not install Gradle distribution from 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip'.

Caused by: java.io.IOException: HTTPS hostname wrong:  should be <services.gradle.org>
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.checkURLSpoofing(HttpsClient.java:566)
```

I tried creating a project with only a wear module, as well as a project with both mobile and wear - the result is the same. If I call `./gradlew build` from the console, it compiles, but I cannot make Android Studio work for some reason. Btw, it works just fine when I work on a project without wear modules.

Has anybody encountered this problem? I'm running Android Studio 1.4. Should I downgrade to some older version?